# How to re-export type declarations imported from a declaration file when compiling to a JavaScript module?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-modules

I have a module written in TypeScript (demonstration source code is here: https://github.com/thejohnfreeman/bugs/tree/dece04bc4353bfc3f100c11fd38a4bb76cfcad67/parent)
It has two source files:

```
// src/index.ts
export { String } from './types'
```

```
// src/types.d.ts
export type String = string
```

I can build `parent` as a JavaScript module:

```
yarn
npx tsc --project tsconfig.json --outDir out --module esnext
```

It compiles only the `.ts` file, and produces what I would expect,
a JavaScript module exporting an empty object:

```js
// out/index.js
export {};
```

But if I change the `.ts` file to export *everything* from the `.d.ts` file,
like this:

```
// src/index.ts
export * from './types'
```

then I get an identical re-export statement in the output:

```js
// out/index.js
export * from './types';
```

and because the `.d.ts` file produces no `.js` output, the import from
`'./types'` is dangling.

Is this a bug?
I expect TypeScript to recognize that everything re-exported from
`'./types'` is a type declaration, and for the `export * from './types'` line
to be compiled to nothing, just as if I had manually named every export from
`'./types'`.

I'm using TypeScript 4.2.4.

Comment: Not sure about the expected behaviour, but you might try [`export type * from './types';`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export)?

Comment: That gives `error TS1383: Only named exports may use 'export type'.`

Comment: Aw. I suppose the proper solution would be not to export types from a separate module anyway, but just name it `src/index.d.ts` - the type definitions for the `index` module.

Comment: The use case that I pruned this problem down from has many declaration files that I'm re-exporting from the main module, as a workaround because TypeScript does not support [submodule exports](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8305). If I add a sibling `index.d.ts` alongside `index.ts` that contains `export * from './types'`, my dependent project doesn't find those declarations when it imports. So far, my only workaround is to compile the `index.ts` by hand and keep `index.js` and `index.d.ts` only.